# Giftedchat scroll not working if dragging slow on background

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I have been looking for a possible answer to this, but to no avail.

The scroll is ok

1.- When the user drags (either fast or slowly), starting over any of the bubbles

2.- If the scroll still has some momentum.

But it doesn't when dragging slowly starting over the background.

Am I mising something in the giftedchat props?

[image: giftedchat slow drag bug]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found where my bug was.
I was wrapping the giftedchat view with a TouchableWithoutFeedback view to hide the "attach" menu when pressed in, and was conflicting the giftedchat scroll logic.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPressIn={()=>{this.setState({showAttachMenu:false})}}>
<GiftedChat ....
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<GiftedChat
    //inverted={false}
    optionTintColor='black'
    isTyping={true}
    renderBubble={this.renderBubble}
    messages={this.state.messages}
    messagesContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'indigo' }}
    onSend={this.onSend}
    user={{
        _id: 1,
    }}
    placeholder='Write a message...'
    renderInputToolbar={this.renderInputToolbar}
    alignTop={false}
    listViewProps={{contentContainerStyle: {flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}}
/>
```

The above is my gifted chat component code, when I wrap inside view tag with height its working, but unable to scroll messages.